# Php explode loop up to value

Tags: php

I want to break the line I pulled from the database and list the ip addresses

Sql Table export
a:3{i:0;s:13:"213.74.219.18";i:1;s:13:"321.32.321.32";i:2;s:14:"321.315.212.55";}

```
$set=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM simple_stats_options where option='ignored_ips'");
$value = mysqli_fetch_array($set,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

function arasinial($str,$birinci,$ikinci,$i) {
   $bolum = explode ($birinci,$str); 
   $bolum = explode ($ikinci,$bolum[$i]); 
   return $bolum[0];
}

$array = explode('/', $var);
foreach ($array as $values)
{

}
$metin=$value["value"];

for ($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) {
 echo arasinial($metin,':"','";',$x)."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is serialized data, so you can just use [unserialize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php):

```
<?php
$r = 'a:3:{i:0;s:13:"213.74.219.18";i:1;s:13:"321.32.321.32";i:2;s:14:"321.315.212.55";}';
print_r(unserialize($r));
```

will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 213.74.219.18
    [1] => 321.32.321.32
    [2] => 321.315.212.55
)
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't know how to do array operations. how can i integrate it or can you provide a resource `$ips = $_POST["ipadresi"];
mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM simple_stats_visits WHERE remote_ip=".$ips."");';`